# Initializing struct structure member consisting of an int and a char pointer?

Tags: c, struct

Here are the structure declarations:

```
typedef struct line
{
    int width;
    char *theLine;
} Line;

typedef struct screen
{
    int width;
    int height;
    Line *theScreen;
} Screen;
```

Here is what I am using to try an initialize the Screen structure:

```
int main()
{
    Screen b = {20, 40, {40, "-"}};
}
```

When I compile the above the result is:

```
warning: braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
Screen b = {20, 40, {40, "-"}};
^
```

What am I doing wrong in the structure initialization? Also, once I am able to compile the code above, how would I access each member of the Line variable withing the struct screen? Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined the 3rd member as a pointer. With `Line theScreen;` instead of `Line *theScreen;`, your initialization code would work.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I realized this as well, but I believe it to be part of the assignment to make it work with a pointer.Even though it seems inefficient.

Comment: @WillyFiallo `Screen b = {20, 40, &(Line){40, "-"}};`

Comment: (^One way to allocate the Line struct and get a pointer to it)

Comment: Thank you for your help!